# How can I take a photo when battery <20%?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery, camera

How can I take photo when battery level is less than 20%? My Samsung Galaxy S always says "battery low" and then closes the camera application when I try to. Is there a way to get around this? Or is 19% not powerful enough to take a photograph (my camera has no flash).

Comment: I would not recommended doing so regularly, regularly discharging a battery to less than 20% will shorten the battery's life.

Comment: off topic: really? why? What I heard was discharging the battery to lowest possible before charging it helped prolong battery life.

Comment: That was only applicable to older chemistries such as NiCad, because they developed a "memory" of the discharge depth - repeatedly recharging before full discharge would decrease the storage capacity. Modern lithium ion cells do not have this memory affect. They loose capacity based on age, temperature (excessive heat impacts life) and time spent at very low charge levels.

Comment: @Fitri: just like Saiboogu said, having a low charge level is bad for modern Lithium batteries.

Comment: ok thanks guys, I wrote another question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/when-should-i-start-charging-my-lithium-battery) in order to ask more information :)

Comment: @Lie Ryan: If that is so, why does the recharge warning is issued at 12% ?

Comment: @Edelcom: the point is low battery level is bad for lithium's longevity, it is up to individual applications to determine what level they consider "low"; obviously the lower you go, the worse it is for the battery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try downloading and using a third-camera app from the market. The restriction is apparently on the stock camera app, not on the hardware (the camera itself). I downloaded [Retro Camera](http://www.urbian.biz/apps/retrocam/), and it is able to take a picture when my Galaxy S is on low battery. That might not be the app you want, so do a search on the market with the keyword "Camera".

Comment: +1 but Retro Camera takes "gimmicky" stylized pictures, if you want something that'll take a more normal picture and has similar options to a normal compact, digital camera, try something like Camera 360 http://www.appbrain.com/app/camera-360/vStudio.Android.GPhoto

Answer (score 6):

This is, unfortunately, not adjustable in the stock version of Android. If you root there are 3rd party versions that modify this low battery level.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a solution. It's pretty simple - just try to hold the Menu button. The info about battery disappears and allows you to use the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the flashlight on it works on the Galaxy Core Prime. Turn the flashlight on first then take your photos.

Comment: What exactly does this accomplish?