# Is it safe to keep Android charging through USB all day?

Tags: battery-life

When I'm in front of the computer, I always keep my Android phone plugged into a USB cable so it's always at a 100% charge and I can type text messages from the convenience of my PC keyboard.

Still, I was wondering if charging a battery when it's already 100% charged hurts: Will it "wear out", ie. won't hold as long?

Generally speaking, is there a good article that explains how to charge and use the main types of batteries? For instance, I seem to remember that some batteries must never be left below 20% charge.

FWIW, I upgraded the original battery in my Samsung Galaxy Nexus to a slightly bigger Li-Ion 1900mAh.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/16575); see also: [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4003/16575)

Comment: Also related: [How frequently is it okay to let the battery discharge fully or as low as possible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33704/16575)