# Should I charge phone overnight or let battery down to a minimum?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

For many times I found myself in a situation, that my battery charge was about 25-30% when I was going to sleep. Since I was always told to not let battery down below 20% (correct me, if that's wrong) I was faced with two options in this situation:

- plug phone to charger and let it charge for entire night,
- leave it and let it down to about 10-15%, that is below *wrong* level for battery charge.

I was always wondering, what option is best for my battery's life and phone's overall performance.

Can someone provide information, which option is better in mentioned situation?

Comment: I'm always charging if it's possible. So when I'm leaving home or workplace, all devices are at 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never let it run down below 10% if you can help it. Running down to "absolute zero" harms your battery (and might even render it inoperable – which is why most devices shut-down before reaching that point). Modern LiIo batteries don't suffer from "memory effect", so ideally you'd plug-in a charger whenever possible: "trickle-charging" doesn't hurt them, low charge (less than 5% definitely) shortens their life-span.

For details, please check with...

- our [battery-life tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info)
- [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575)
- [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/16575)
- [Wikipedia: Lithium Ion batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion)
- our [battery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery/info)
- [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4003/16575)
- [How frequently is it okay to let the battery discharge fully or as low as possible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33704/16575)