# Xiaomi Redmi 2 Pro Battery Issues

Tags: battery, charging, xiaomi

I have a Redmi 2 Pro, and it works fine, except for some issues with the battery. If I charge it to 100% before I disconnect the charger and go to sleep, by the morning it may go down only to 98%, but if I leave it on around 70% for the night it can even shut down by the time i wake up. In every case I use CleanMaster to shut unnecessary apps down before I go to bed. The possible shutdown makes it completely unreliable when it comes to morning alarms.

One solution may be to leave it on charger for the whole night, but i heard  about it being damaging to the battery. Is it? What can i do?

Comment: Can you take a back up of your data and do factory reset to see if the problem continues? What ate all the battery related apps instated on your phone? Android version? Device , is it rooted?

Comment: Don't use cleanmaster and similar apps. They do more harm than good. Also, don't kill tasks manually until you absolutely need to (app is not responding)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, it appears that the problem could be due to any of the following factors:

1. **Weak/Dying Battery:** Can be verified by changing the battery
2. **System not going to deep sleep:** Could be due to wakelocks letting the system alive either from apps or system like media server. Clean Master may say that it had killed apps, but it cannot kill apps completely , including background processes unless it has root capability and is designed to do so. Neither does it ask for root permissions nor does the app description claim it can kill background processes, so one cannot trust that it is really killing your apps

I would first suggest that you do a factory reset after taking a back up of your data. I am presuming your device is not rooted, so you can see this for taking a back up [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices). This solution does not cater for SMS, contacts/ calendar which can be done using [CM backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbackup)

Instructions for doing a factory reset for your device [here](http://en.miui.com/thread-135914-1-1.html). If the problem persists after factory reset, then I would suggest you to change your battery.

I am hopeful that this should resolve the problem. Please revert with Irvine and edit your question with additional information sought in the comments section, which would come in useful if the problem is not resolved

Coming to your other question, leaving it on charger overnight is **not recommended**, since the Battery gets internally hot and stress caused by this reduces battery life as you can read  [Find out how to prolong battery life by using correct charge methods.](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)
. Related inputs for additional reading [Should I charge phone overnight or let battery down to a minimum?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/should-i-charge-phone-overnight-or-let-battery-down-to-a-minimum?s=1|0.4571)

**Edit**

Are you on MUI 3.6.6.0? Asking since rapid battery drain seems to be a problem , unresolved till mid last year, as per reports [here](http://en.miui.com/thread-135914-1-1.html)

In any case, your device has the facility to identify battery consumption separately for hardware and software (app wise) as shown in screen shot below taken from the same source. Can you study that to identify the culprit, in case of rapid drain? You can quickly weed out the battery hogging apps using this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can say one thing based on my experince.. i have a samsung galaxy tab 3. I had these issue.. below 70% the battery has some kind of wierd problems. I was using some apps that claims to free memory etc like clean master, 360 security, battery saver etc. I dont know specifically what i used. But that was the reason. Android has inbuilt ram and battery management. These apps doesnt do anything but harms. They take huge space in memory and drains battery faster. Better delete such apps and check your battery..

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "Clean Master" and its ad-click actions.