# Initial Charge Problems

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

I bought my Android last January and I forgot to charge it for 8 hours.

What will be the effect on my Android and  battery life? ( battery type is Lithium Polymer)

Comment: a) it will bite you, b) it will explode, c) it will survive? I recommend for reading: 1) our [battery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery/info) (and especially [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4003/16575)), 2) our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info), 3) the questions using one of those tags. Oh, and welcome to the Android Enthusiasts!

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, Li Polymer has the same charge/discharge characteristics as Lithium ion, the [underlying chemistry being the same](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery). For more information see [Li-Ion vs Li-Poly, plus how do Lithium batteries work anyway?](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/15775_How_do_Lithium_batteries_work.php)
- When the phone is marketed, manufacturers, typically charge the battery to around 40% as you may have noticed. This is good for battery longevity and ensures battery degradation does not occur on storage. See [BU-702: How to Store Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries) for better understanding
- **There isn't** a valid reason for charging the batteries for xx hours before first use or to charge till 100%. It is yet another charging myth , see [misconception # 6](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-common-misconceptions-about-mobile-device-batteries/)

So, **not charging for 8 hours does not matter** and your battery is pretty much in the same shape as it was.

See [BU-415: How to Charge and When to Charge?](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table) for a general understanding of charging "do's and don'ts)

Additional information on this site that would help you care for your batteries

- [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone)
- [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)
- [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/when-should-i-start-charging-my-lithium-battery) (thanks to [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137199/initial-charge-problems/137203#comment174455_137199) for pointing out)