# What can I do to slow down battery degradation of portable power bank for my Android phone?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

I just got [Inland USB-A 5,200mAh Power Bank w/ LED Indicators](https://www.microcenter.com/product/615765/inland-usb-a-5,200mah-power-bank-w--led-indicators---gold) for my android phone. It has a one-year warrantee, which  seems to tell that its battery might degrade significantly after one year of uses.

The power bank came fully charged. I don't have  a plan of using it sometime soon, except for something unexpectedly, and will just set it aside for weeks or even months. I was wondering how to slow down battery degradation as much as possible?

For example:

- In what percentage of charge shall I leave it, when I set it aside? Emptily, fully charged, or somewhere between?
- Does its battery degradation depend on how many times it has been  discharged and then charged, and how often it has been ?

Answer (score 1):

Power banks too have the same type of batteries as Android devices (Li-Ion or Li-Po) so the answers covering points you raised are :

> In what percentage of charge shall I leave it, when I set it aside? Emptily, fully charged, or somewhere between?

**40%** is the best for storage

Quoting from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/137203/131553)

> > When the phone is marketed, manufacturers, typically charge the battery to around 40% as you may have noticed. This is good for battery longevity and ensures battery degradation does not occur on storage. See [BU-702: How to Store Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries) for better understanding

> Does its battery degradation depend on how many times it has been discharged and then charged, and how often it has been ?

Quoting from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167481/131553)

> > **Yes**. The more you use the battery , more the number of discharge cycles ( which covers both charging and discharging as explained earlier) and drop in battery capacity... (see answer for graphs and picture)

Now, the unasked part, charging while in use, see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156538/131553)

> > charge when the battery drops to 50% and stop charging at 80 or 90%.

You may want to look at [hardware solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213869/131553) for the last point.